# How do I solve this error, "Cannot assign value of type 'User?' to type 'String?'?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I want to fetch user data from Firebase Realtime Database so that the navigationItem.title will appear as a user's username. I am having trouble (I'm new to coding), so I feel like I am missing a lot of code while also not understanding the use for code like 'observeSingleEvent,' if I am not looking to Login a user, I just want their username (that I hope to fetch from the Firestore Database) to appear in a navigation bar.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         var ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")

       ref = Database.database().reference()
        
             let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                   
            self.navigationItem.title = user       "Error: Cannot assign value of type 'User?' to type 'String?'"
        

    

        func setCustomBackImage() {
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
       

    setCustomBackImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }
    
    
    

}
```

I know I am missing a lot of gaps, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sir user is on object and and you need the user name for assigning as a title / you can access the object property like that user.username whatever you set it.

Comment: Can you please expand on this (is there a way I can assign the username as an object)? Since I’m more of visual learner I need to see how this can be done tangibly.

Comment: no you cannot assign username as an object you need a string. See User is an object in which username is property of it. to access the username you need to do like this user.username to set text in your scenario.